# Is it true that these angles are equal?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, billiards

Suppose we have a line $l$ and points $A$ and $B$ which are on different sides of $l$. Point $P$ is on line $l$.  When we maximize $|PA-PB|$, it seems that the angle formed by $PA$ an $l$ is equal to the angle formed by $PB$ and $l$ is equal.  Why is this?

Also, if we take a hyperbola with foci $A$ and $B$ and a point $P$ on the hyperbola, such that there is a line tangent to the hyperbola at point $P$, it appears that again, the angle formed by $PA$ an $l$ is equal to the angle formed by $PB$ and $l$ is equal.  Again, why does this property hold for hyperbolas?

Comment: Are $A$, $B$ and $l$ fixed, with $P$ sliding along $l$ ?

Comment: Do you mean for the second part?

Comment: The question does not say what is fixed and what is allowed to vary in order to maximize $|PA-PB|$.

Answer (score 0):

i can answer the first question.

let $A'$ be the image of $A$ on the line $l.$ look at the triangle $PBA'.$ by the triangle inequality $|PA' - PB| \le A'B$ and the equality occurs when $P, A', B$ are collinear. that shows that $AP$ and $BP$ make the same angle with $l.$